# Python multiprocessing: terminate processes by arguments after exceeding timeout

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I would like to calculate running time of a long-running function for different values of `k` and `n`.
For example: `k = [2,3,...,100]` and `n = [50,100,150,200,...,1000]`

If a running time of a specific `(k, n)` tuple exceeds a specific amount of time (say, `60 seconds`) I would like to stop the execution of every process with a greater `n` (and set the running time to `inf`).
For example if `n = 500` timed-out, I would like to cancel execution of all tasks with `n >= 500`.

I tried using Python's `multiprocessing.Pool` and `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` but I couldn't find a way to cancel the running tasks. As far as I found, there's no way to cancel it while it's running.

I think that maybe I should address this problem in a different way.

Please advise.

```py
import multiprocessing
import random
import time
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import product
from multiprocessing import Pool

n_list = [n * 50 for n in range(1, 21)]
k_list = [k for k in range(2, 31)]
k_n_list = list(product(k_list, n_list))

def long_running_function(k, n):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    time.sleep(random.randint(2,120))
    end_time = datetime.now()
    running_time = end_time - start_time

    return k, n, running_time.total_seconds()


running_times = []

with Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
    async_results = []
    for k, n in k_n_list:
        async_results.append((k, n, pool.apply_async(func=long_running_function, args=(k, n))))

    for k, n, result in async_results:
        try:
            process_result = result.get(60)  # timeout after 60 seconds
            running_times.append(process_result)

        except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
            print(f"Timeout for k = {k}, n = {n}")
            running_times.append((k, n, float('inf')))

            # HERE I WOULD LIKE TO CANCEL EVERY TASK WITH N >= n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should be aware of is that the following statement ...

```py
process_result = result.get(60)  # timeout after 60 seconds
```

... will raise a `multiprocessing.TimeoutError` if the task associated with the `result` has not completed, *but it does not terminate the task; the task continues to run*. However, when `pool.terminate()` is called, either implicitly in your case when you exit your `with Pool ... as pool:` block or if explicitly called, then all processes in the pool (and of course the tasks they are currently running) will be terminated. But don't even think about using a process pool created with `concurrent.futures`; there is no method that will terminate processes before all tasks have completed.

Second, you are running `k * n` tasks in a process pool size of `os.cpu_count()` where the number of tasks can be much greater than the number of processes in the pool that you have. Therefore, it is possible that when you discover that one of your tasks has not completed within 60 seconds, there are still many tasks that have not even started to run. This will always be problematic since you will be giving 60 seconds for all tasks with certain `n` values to complete, but many haven't even had a chance to start before they will be terminated.

Third, in your loop where you execute ...

```py
process_result = result.get(60)
```

The `AsynchResult` instance against which you are testing this may return a result after 3 seconds (and not timeout). **But 3 seconds have elapsed since you submitted the tasks.** On the next iteration you only want to now be waiting 57 seconds for the next result!

One possible solution is to use a `multiprocessing.Value` instance stored in shared memory across all processes and thus visible to all tasks initialized to `sys.maxsize`. Periodically your worker functions must inspect the value of this `Value` and if less or equal to the value of `n` they are processing, it is a signal for the worker function to gracefully return immediately. Therefore, the code becomes something like the followingg (note that I have changed some of the parameters for demo purposes):

```py
import multiprocessing
import random
import time
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import product
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value
import sys
import ctypes


def init_pool(v):
    global stop_n
    stop_n = v

def long_running_function(k, n):
    print('n =', n)
    start_time = datetime.now()
    #sleep_time = random.randint(2, 10)
    sleep_time = n / 100 + .3
    t_stop = time.time() + sleep_time
    while time.time() < t_stop:
        if n >= stop_n.value:
            print('quitting because my n is', n)
            break
        time.sleep(.1)
    end_time = datetime.now()
    running_time = end_time - start_time

    return k, n, running_time.total_seconds()


# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_list = [n * 50 for n in range(1, 20)]
    k_list = [k for k in range(2, 3)]
    k_n_list = list(product(k_list, n_list))

    running_times = []

    stop_n = Value(ctypes.c_ulonglong,  sys.maxsize)

    # best to leave one processor free for main process
    with Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(stop_n,)) as pool:
        async_results = []
        for k, n in k_n_list:
            async_results.append((k, n, pool.apply_async(func=long_running_function, args=(k, n))))

        TIMEOUT = 4 # timeout after 4 seconds
        start_time = time.time()
        for k, n, result in async_results:
            try:
                time_to_wait = TIMEOUT - (time.time() - start_time)
                if time_to_wait < 0:
                    time_to_wait = 0
                process_result = result.get(time_to_wait)
            except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
                # signal to tasks whose n argument is >= than this value of n:
                print('setting stop value to', n)
                stop_n.value = n
                break

        # now process actual results:
        for k, n, result in async_results:
            process_result = result.get()
            running_times.append(process_result)
        print(running_times)
```

Prints:

```
n = 50
n = 100
n = 150
n = 200
n = 250
n = 300
n = 350
n = 400
n = 450
n = 500
n = 550
n = 600
n = 650
n = 700
setting stop value to 400
quitting because my n is 400
n = 750
quitting because my n is 750
n = 800
quitting because my n is 800
quitting because my n is 500
quitting because my n is 450
n = 850
n = 900
n = 950
quitting because my n is 850
quitting because my n is 900
quitting because my n is 950
quitting because my n is 550
quitting because my n is 600
quitting because my n is 650
quitting because my n is 700
[(2, 50, 0.803502), (2, 100, 1.306462), (2, 150, 1.807341), (2, 200, 2.308982), (2, 250, 2.812402), (2, 300, 3.315068), (2, 350, 3.81634), (2, 400, 3.114924), (2, 450, 2.627066), (2, 500, 2.124075), (2, 550, 1.607504), (2, 600, 1.104059), (2, 650, 0.604383), (2, 700, 0.100104), (2, 750, 0.001005), (2, 800, 0.000999), (2, 850, 0.002), (2, 900, 0.001999), (2, 950, 0.001999)]
```

You will observe that on my desktop with 8 cores, 7 of which have been assigned to the pool, several tasks are waiting to start at the time that the shared `Value` is set to `400` so that when they do start they immediately terminate (you can see that their running time is very small). As I said, what you are trying to this way is problematic. **It would be better that after the `Value` is set with a value of `n`, that each task for which this is applicable instead of returning immediately, gave itself a certain number of seconds to complete.**

**Update**

If you want tasks that have already started main proceessing to complete regardless (because they then have no way to check `stop_n`), change `long_range_function` to:

```py
def long_running_function(k, n):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    print('n =', n)
    if n < stop_n.value:
        #time.sleep(random.randint(2, 10))
        time.sleep(n / 100 + .3)
    else:
        print('quitting because my n is', n)
    end_time = datetime.now()
    running_time = end_time - start_time

    return k, n, running_time.total_seconds()
```

It now prints:

```
n = 50
n = 100
n = 150
n = 200
n = 250
n = 300
n = 350
n = 400
n = 450
n = 500
n = 550
n = 600
n = 650
n = 700
setting stop value to 400
n = 750
quitting because my n is 750
n = 800
quitting because my n is 800
n = 850
quitting because my n is 850
n = 900
quitting because my n is 900
n = 950
quitting because my n is 950
[(2, 50, 0.801908), (2, 100, 1.300968), (2, 150, 1.800735), (2, 200, 2.301075), (2, 250, 2.800968), (2, 300, 3.301077), (2, 350, 3.800717), (2, 400, 4.301718), (2, 450, 4.801664), (2, 500, 5.301043), (2, 550, 5.800506), (2, 600, 6.300665), (2, 650, 6.800603), (2, 700, 7.301471), (2, 750, 0.0), (2, 800, 0.0), (2, 850, 0.0), (2, 900, 0.0), (2, 950, 0.001015)]
```

Comment: Thank you, @Booboo! Is it possible to accomplish your suggestion without checking for `n` in the worker thread? Actually my worker runs some library function. I don't have any "while loop" (or something similar) to check it periodically. Maybe I should just let them finish and check only on start..

Comment: Now you are saying tasks already running should just be allowed to finish since they are unable to check (presumably the value `stop_n.value`) because there is no `while loop`. I get that. I also get that they can, however, check at task startup. What I don't get is what you mean by "without checking for n." You need to compare `n` with `stop_n.value` at the beginning of `long_running_function`.

Comment: See updated `long_running_function` with new output.